# How to use default image as featured image by implement some code in function.php

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I want to use a default image as a featured image for all those Posts and Pages, where is not any selected featured image from media.
I have tried this code in **function.php** but not working,

```
function filter_post_thumbnail( $html ) {
    if ( '' == $html ) {
        return '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Google_Lens_-_new_logo.png" />';
    }
    // Else, return the post thumbnail
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'filter_post_thumbnail' );
```

Have any solution by implementing some piece of code in **function.php** file?

Comment: Did Rups response answer your question? I see you've not left any comments but you also haven't upvoted or accepted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your existing code work you'll also need to override [`has_post_thumbnail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/has_post_thumbnail/):

```php
add_filter( 'has_post_thumbnail', '__return_true' );
```

since your theme is probably guarding get_the_post_thumbnail() with [has_post_thumbnail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/), so that now needs to return true in the default case.

---

However there's still a chance that this won't work, if the theme you're using goes directly to [`get_post_thumbnail_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_thumbnail_id/). To make that work, you'll need to have an ID for your image: either

1. upload the image to the media library
2. pick an out-of-range ID, e.g. -123, to be the thumbnail attachment ID and then fake the image by hooking `image_downsize` (I think!)

   ```
   function image_downsize_default_thumbnail( $downsize, $id, $size )
   {
       if ( $id == -123 )
       {
           return array(
               'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Google_Lens_-_new_logo.png',
               1024, 1024, false );
       }
       return $downsize;
   }
   ```

and then add a `default_post_metadata` hook to fill in the missing thumbnail ID when absent, which is the postmeta key `_thumbnail_id`:

```
function default_post_metadata__thumbnail_id( $value, $object_id, $meta_key,
                                              $single, $meta_type )
{
    if ( '_thumbnail_id' == $meta_key )
    {
        $value = -123; // the attachment ID for the default image
    }
    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'default_post_metadata', 'default_post_metadata__thumbnail_id', 10, 5 );
```

(We can ignore $single as `get_metadata_default()` will wrap the value in an array if necessary, although `get_post_thumbnail_id()` passes $single = true anyway.)

With this filter you shouldn't need to hook has_post_thumbnail and post_thumbnail_html, as it should pick up the default image as if it were the real thumbnail. You could look up the default ID from a post or from an option here too if you'd prefer rather than hard-coding it.